# Get Karma Coverage to Open the report with Grunt

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

Karma Coverage seems to generate the coverages in subfolders with a name like: `PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X)`, anyway to tell it to open that subfolder when using in combination with Grunt?

Currently one would have to go to the directory copy the name of the directory and paste it after the opened `localhost:5555` to get it to load.

It might not be a big deal but I am trying to cut that step of copying and pasting.

P.S. I am already using text type to output directly in the command line for easy access but I'd love to have it open the HTML coverage report when I need it.

```
connect: {
  coverage: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: 'coverage/<<NEED TO GET THE DYNAMIC F>>',
      port: 5555,
      keepalive: true
    }
  }
}

unit_coverage: {
  configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
  autoWatch: false,
  singleRun: true,
  reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
  preprocessors: {
    'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js': ['coverage']
  },
  coverageReporter: {
    reporters: [
      {type : 'text'},
      {type: 'html', dir: '/coverage'}
    ]
  }
},

grunt.registerTask('coverage', [
  'karma:html_coverage',
  'connect:coverage'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to be able to open the latest version of the karma coverage report for Chrome (I test two browsers, but encountered the bug that Emma Gou mentioned). This was a quick and dirty solution that relies on grunt file expand returning a sorted array of matching files. An explicit sort could be added.

```
open: {
  server: {
    path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
  },
  coverage: {
    path: function () {
      var reports = grunt.file.expand('coverage/Chrome*/index.html');
      return reports[reports.length - 1].toString();
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the *karma-runner* documentation you can specify **dir** to the **coverageReporter** and it will be used to store the generated reports.

Comment: @carlodurso  
coverageReporter = {  
  type : 'html',  
  dir : 'coverage/'  
}  
type  
Possible Values:  
html (default)  
lcov (lcov and html)  
lcovonly  
text  
text-summary  
cobertura (xml format supported by Jenkins)  
If you set type to text or text-summary, you may set the file option, like this.  
coverageReporter = {  
  type : 'text',  
  dir : 'coverage/',  
  file : 'coverage.txt'  
}  
If no filename is given, it will write the output to the console.  
dir  
Type: String  
Output for coverage reports. When you set a relative path, the directory is resolved against the basePath.